# Using BigDecimal in JAXB marshalling

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, marshalling

I have a REST webservice with JAXB fields annotations.
For example,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class MyClass{
  private BigDecimal sum;
  //+ getter and setter
}
```

If field "sum" contains big value, for example, 1234567890.12345, it marshalls to 1.23456789012345E9
How to write a rule for marshalling only this class?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create adaptor

```
puclic class BigDecimalAdaptor implements XmlAdapter<String, BigDecimal>
```

and use for `(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` access

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BigDecimalAdaptor.class)
private BigDecimal sum;
```

and for `(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)` access

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BigDecimalAdaptor.class)  
public getSum()
{
   return sum;
}
```

adaptor can be like

```
public class BigDecimalAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, BigDecimal>{

    @Override
    public String marshal(BigDecimal value) throws Exception 
    {
        if (value!= null)
        {
            return value.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal unmarshal(String s) throws Exception 
    {
       return new BigDecimal(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You write an `XmlAdapter<String, BigDecimal>` and you annotate the getter of sum with it:
`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BigDecimalStringAdapter.class)`.