# How to register handler to JAXB annotated class that uses XmlAdapter, in order to send a REST Resource client an error message?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs

I was looking into [Using BigDecimal in JAXB marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910413/using-bigdecimal-in-jaxb-marshalling)

What is happening by default, is that Exception gets thrown, but no handler is listening to it. As a result, such request reaches JAR-RS method, but with field thad was submitted with "incorrect" value, set to NULL.

I read in the JAVADOC, that a handler must be set, so that I could do something when such case happens. But I can't find an information on how to setup such handler.

My endpoint is something like:

```
@Path("/path")
public class MyResource {

    @POST
    @Path("something")
    public Response postSomething(JaxbAnnotatedRequest request) {
        //processing....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any real elegant way to handle this. But to answer your question

> "I read in the [JAVADOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html#unmarshal%28ValueType%29), that a handler must be set, so that I could do something when such case happens. But I can't find an information on how to setup such handler."

the unmarshalling will be done in a [`MessageBodyReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html). The [`ValidationEventHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler.html) should be registered with the [`Unmarshaller`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html), which is created for each request. So we would need to somehow tap into the currently used `MessageBodyReader`, which I am not really sure how to do, or if adding a handler this way is even configurable. If it is, I'm sure it's implementation specific.

One way though is to write your own `MessageBodyReader` to handle this specific type. For example

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;

@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class JaxbAnnotatedRequestMessageBodyReader
        implements MessageBodyReader<JaxbAnnotatedRequest> {

    JAXBContext context;

    public JaxbAnnotatedRequestMessageBodyReader() {
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JaxbAnnotatedRequest.class);
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type type1,
            Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        return JaxbAnnotatedRequest.class == type;
    }

    @Override
    public JaxbAnnotatedRequest readFrom(Class<JaxbAnnotatedRequest> type, Type type1,
            Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt, MultivaluedMap<String, String> mm,
            InputStream in) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        try {
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {

                @Override
                public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
                    String nfe = NumberFormatException.class.getCanonicalName();
                    if (nfe.equals(event.getMessage())) {
                        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(400)
                                .entity("Bad Number Formatting").build());
                    }
                    System.out.println(event.getMessage());
                    return false;
                }

            });
            JaxbAnnotatedRequest request
                    = (JaxbAnnotatedRequest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(in);
            return request;

        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(400).entity(
                    "Caught JAXBEception: " + ex.toString()).build());
        }
    }
}
```

The `ValidationEventHandler` is set up on the `Unmarshaller` in the `readFrom` method.

Another option (though also with limitations), is to use [Bean Validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html), which is part of the JAX-RS 2.0 spec. You may want to look into your implementation's documentation, if you want to use this feature. The only problem with this is the say you were to use the `@NotNull` annotation, you would know if the request value was actually null, or if it was set null by JAXB, so you would need to send some generic message.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the problem you have is a validation issue. Input validation today is an inevitable responsibility of the developer. In case of data files like JSON or XML this can easily be done by using `schema validation`. This validation needs to be integrated into the data conversion process, recommendable in both marshalling and unmarhalling. In case of `null` values or any other inappropriate input, like a to short post code, etc. an `JAXBException` will be thrown, which in turn can be wrapped into a more expressive exception. Finally you have to declare an `ExceptionMapper` which will catch the exception and responde with an appropriaten message to the caller. Below you will find an example.

---

**The entity class Address.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "address", namespace = DataEntity.NSP)
public class Address implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2508433924387468026L;

    private Integer id;
    private String street;
    private String number;
    private Short zipCode;
    private String city;

    protected Address() {

    }

    public Address(final Integer id, final String street, final String number,
            final Short zipCode, final String city) {
        setId(id);
        setStreet(street);
        setNumber(number);
        setZipCode(zipCode);
        setCity(city);
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId(Integer id) {
        ValidationHelper.validateId(id);

        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = DataEntity.NSP)
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    private void setStreet(String street) {
        ValidationHelper.validateAddressStreet(street);

        this.street = street;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = DataEntity.NSP)
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    private void setNumber(String number) {
        ValidationHelper.validateAddressNumber(number);

        this.number = number;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = DataEntity.NSP)
    public Short getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    private void setZipCode(Short zipCode) {
        ValidationHelper.validateAddressZipCode(zipCode);

        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = DataEntity.NSP)
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    private void setCity(String city) {
        ValidationHelper.validateAddressCity(city);

        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

---

**The schema validation files:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="https://localhost/JAX-RS_BookStore_Service/xsd/" targetNamespace="https://localhost/JAX-RS_BookStore_Service/xsd/"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:pref="https://localhost/JAX-RS_BookStore_Service/xsd/">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="Types.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="address" type="addressType" />
</xs:schema>
```

**The generic xsd types:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="https://localhost/JAX-RS_BookStore_Service/xsd/"
    targetNamespace="https://localhost/JAX-RS_BookStore_Service/xsd/"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:pref="https://localhost/JAX-RS_BookStore_Service/xsd/">

    <xs:simpleType name="unsignedInteger">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="addressStreet">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß -]{2,32}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="addressNumber">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1}[0-9a-z/\\ -]{0,7}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="addressCity">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß -]{2,32}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="zipCodeMoreThan4Digits">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:short">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1000"></xs:minInclusive>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="9999"></xs:maxInclusive>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="addressType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="city" type="addressCity" />
            <xs:element name="number" type="addressNumber" />
            <xs:element name="street" type="addressStreet" />
            <xs:element name="zipCode" type="zipCodeMoreThan4Digits" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="unsignedInteger" use="required">
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**The abstract `MessageBodyReader` which is used by several implementations. In this class the XML input is validated against the schema file.**

```
    public abstract class AbstractXmlValidationReader<T> implements
        MessageBodyReader<T> {

    private final Providers providers;
    private final Schema schema;

    /**
     * Instantiates the XML validation class (MessageBodyReader)
     * 
     * @param providers
     * @param servletContext
     * @param xsdFileName
     */
    public AbstractXmlValidationReader(final Providers providers,
            final ServletContext servletContext, final String xsdFileName) {
        this.providers = providers;

        try {
            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory
                    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            File xsd = new File(servletContext.getRealPath(xsdFileName));
            schema = sf.newSchema(xsd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to create XSD validation schema", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<T> readableClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        if (type == readableClass
                && type.isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Source adapted from: <a href=
     * "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service"
     * >stackoverflow.com</a>
     */
    @Override
    public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
            ContextResolver<JAXBContext> resolver = providers
                    .getContextResolver(JAXBContext.class, mediaType);
            if (null != resolver) {
                jaxbContext = resolver.getContext(type);
            }
            if (null == jaxbContext) {
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
            }
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T entity = (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(entityStream);
            return entity;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new MessageBodyReaderValidationException(
                    "Failure while performing xml validation or xml marhalling!",
                    e);
        }
    }
}
```

**The concreate `MeassagBodyReader` implementation, which provides the specific XSD file.**

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class AddressXmlValidationReader extends
        AbstractXmlValidationReader<Address> {

    private final static String xsdFileName = "/xsd/Address.xsd";

    public AddressXmlValidationReader(@Context Providers providers,
            @Context ServletContext servletContext) {
        super(providers, servletContext, xsdFileName);
    }
}
```

**And finally the specific `ExceptionMapper`. The response-body in this example just contains the exception message. Probably this should be changed to sth. different, like HTML.**

*Don't forget to declare this class within the service `Application` class! `classes.add(MessageBodyReaderValidationExceptionMapper.class);`*

```
@Provider
public class MessageBodyReaderValidationExceptionMapper implements
        ExceptionMapper<MessageBodyReaderValidationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MessageBodyReaderValidationException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(e.getMessage()).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

---

**The result of a POST request by using Firefox RESTClient plugin.**

*Note that the content of the `<street>` tag is empty, `NULL` value!*

[image]